# How to display the information of a subobject using ngfor

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I am developing an application with angular and I need to display some data that has the following structure:

```
{
    "id": 33,
    "arg": 7,
    "date": "2022-01-31",
    "User": {
        "Name": "Cristian",
        "Group": {
            "NGroup": "Group 1"
        }
    },
    "Sport": {
        "NSport": "Sport 1"
    }
},
```

The information should be displayed in this way

id | arg | date | Name (User) | NGroup (Group) | NSport (Sport)

For this I was trying to use keyvalue, the problem with this is that when it brings the User object, it shows me an "item" called [object Object] that corresponds to group and there is no way to hide it. This is the current code:

```
                 <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of listItems">
                      <td><div>{{ item.id }}</div></td>                               
                      <td><div>{{ item.arg}}</div></td>
                      <td><div>{{ item.date }}</div></td>
                      <td *ngFor="let key of item.User | keyvalue "><div>{{ key.value }}</div></td>
                      <td *ngFor="let key of item.User | keyvalue"><div *ngFor="let key2 of key.value | keyvalue" >{{ key2.value }}</div></td>                         
                      <td *ngFor="let kv of item.Sports | keyvalue"><div>{{kv.value}}</div></td>                         
                   
                    </tr>  
                  </tbody>
```

The output of this is:

id | arg | date | [Object,Object] | Name(User) | NGroup (Group) | NSport(sport)

**The question is : How could I show only some items of the object and not all the content**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out the items to display using something like this:

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let item of listItems">
 <td><div>{{ item.id }}</div></td>                               
 <td><div>{{ item.arg}}</div></td>
 <td><div>{{ item.date }}</div></td>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let key of item.User | keyvalue ">
  <td *ngIf="isInteresting(key.value)">{{ key.value }}</td>
 </ng-container>

 <td *ngFor="let key of item.User | keyvalue"><div *ngFor="let key2 of 
key.value | keyvalue" >{{ key2.value }}</div></td>                         
 <td *ngFor="let kv of item.Sport | keyvalue"><div>{{kv.value}}</div></td>                         

</tr>  
</table>
```

and in the component:

```
isInteresting(val): boolean { return typeof val !== 'object'; }
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This may be dodging the question, but typically I try to keep component template files simple. It helps keep business logic contained inside your TS file which also enables for better testing scenarios.

Since you know the desired output `id | arg | date | Name (User) | NGroup (Group) | NSport (Sport)` you should use the component's TS file to create that interface for the view. A simple `.map()` should do the job.

```
this.viewItems = this.listItems.map(item=>{
  const { id, arg, date, User, Sport } = item;
  const name = User.Name;
  const nGroup = User.Group.NGroup;
  const nSport = Sport.NSport;
  return { id, arg, date, name, nGroup, nSport };
});
```

Now you only need one `*ngFor` loop for rendering your data.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of viewItems">
    <td><div>{{ item.id }}</div></td>
    <td><div>{{ item.arg}}</div></td>
    <td><div>{{ item.date }}</div></td>
    <td><div>{{ key.name }}</div></td>
    <td><div>{{ key.nGroup }}</div></td>
    <td><div>{{ key.nSport }}</div></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Note: While it's already defined in your source data, I would avoid naming objects with uppercase letters (`User` and `Sport`). This naming style should be reserved for defining classes.